# Microsoft Outlook 2013 Meeting Invitation View / Format

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

[image: Meeting Notice (redacted)]

The attached is an example of a common Meeting Notice.  Displayed is the Meeting Originator (with thumbnail), many of the Attendees (with a scroll bar), "When" and "Location", followed by the Meeting Details (with large scroll-bar).

Notice that about 50% of the window is devoted to "non-Details", and to view all the Details the attendees must scroll down multiple pages.

Is there a way to minimize any piece of, or the entire top 50% of the Meeting Notice?

Answer (score 0):

Have you double click the email to open it in the largest window? Based on my test, the portion of the meeting body is far more than half the size of the entire page, not the size of the graph you provided.

If you are indeed open in the largest window, considering the impact of the font size, it is recommended that you try to reduce the current font to check if there is anything different.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.